# Linux 'runas' equivalent

Tags: linux, security

My company has multiple domains and I log into my local machine with one set of credentials, but often when accessing certain network resources I need to use a different set of credentials. In Windows I would use **RunAs** where I have the option to run the entire process as under a different set of credentials or I could tell it to only impersonate the other user over the network (`runas /netonly`).

Is there something like this in Linux?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$ sudo -u <username> <command>
```

That will run the specified command as the user specified. It's not an exact drop-in for Windows' RunAs function, though, as that incorporates Kerberos authentication as well as for tasks that connect to remote hosts.

Comment: @Mark: look into the different pam authentication modules to add network authentication support (pam_krb5 and pam_ldap are a good place to start)

Comment: ok, but when I try sudo -u [domain2]\\[username] it tells me 'unknown user: [domain2]\[username]'

Comment: @Mark - that would be becuase by default, linux hosts know *nothing* of your AD/Windows environment. It's certainly possible to configure linux to use AD for authentication, but that's a separate question.

Comment: you're right, I've awarded the points and I'll post a new question.

Comment: @Mark Sounds good. Before you post a new question, though, search through old ServerFault questions. There are scads of them relating to integration of linux and Windows.

Answer (score 7):

[sudo](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm) or [su](http://ss64.com/bash/su.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the `runuser` command. Notice that you have to be a root user to use it:

> ```
> runuser -l  userNameHere -c 'command'  
> runuser -l  userNameHere -c '/path/to/command arg1 arg2'  
> runuser -u user -- command1 arg1 arg2
> ```

2. You can use the `su` command. This will work also with a non-root user:

> `su - anotherUser`

See the link for more details:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/